# Googl In-app Verification Server Side Error "Insufficient Permission Error"

Tags: node.js

I am working with Node js for the first time.
There was a problem with the payment verification section.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/inapp/{productId}/purchases/{token}?access_token=Token
```

There is a problem when approaching with the above contents.
Use the Google API

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games_lite
```

Your payment will be processed normally.
However, the issue is on the payment verification side.
The contents of the error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the application used to launch your program (Weather that is a batch file, or command prompt) with administrative permissions.